# DBFlow, GreenDAO, SugarORM or what?

Tags: android, orm

I'm starting with a new app, and I want to know what of these orms is the best, nowadays, DBFlow, GreenDAO, SugarORM.

I've readed that DBFlow is the fastest orm, but I want to know your expertise opinion.

Comment: [Check section: Don't ask ... *Product or service recommendations or comparisons,
Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Ok, sorry. I forgot it.

Comment: You should start a thread on reddit, and post it's link here (replying to me, so I'm aware of that ;) )